# Keep all values added by a method in a separate variable

Tags: python-3.x, class, methods

I want to create a method that adds a row to my variable. What I currently have is the following

```
class Album :
    def __init__(self,nbr,nbr_songs):
        self.header = 'Album ' + str(nbr) + ' (' + str(nbr_songs) + ' songs)')
    
    def add(self,song,n):
        self.line = song
        self.nbre = n     # This is the count of how many song there is

    def __str__(self):
        s = self.header
        s += '\n' + "{:02}".format(self.nbre) + ': ' + str(self.line)
        return s
```

The output wanted is the following

```
Album 1 (3 songs)
01: White_Wedding - Billy_Idol - 00:04:12
02: Stand_And_Deliver - Adam_&_The_Ants - 00:03:33
03: You_Spin_Me_Around - Dead_Or_Alive - 00:03:14
```

The issue is that when I add the three songs to an Album one after the other, it returns the following.

```
Album 1 (3 songs)
01: You_Spin_Me_Around - Dead_Or_Alive - 00:03:14
```

I know that my code is missing something but I can't figure out what.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is by no means a perfect solution but I think it would be a definite improvement to create a separate `Song` class and maybe even an `Artist` one too, and have a **[list](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#lists)** of songs in your `Album` class:

```
class Song:

    def __init__(self, title, artists, duration, album, track_number):
        self.title = title
        self.artists = artists
        self.duration = duration
        self.album = album
        self.track_number = track_number

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.track_number:02}: {self.title} - {self.artists} - {self.duration}'


class Album:

    def __init__(self, number):
        self.number = number
        self.songs = []

    def add_song(self, title, artists, duration):
        track_number = len(self.songs) + 1
        song = Song(title, artists, duration, self, track_number)
        self.songs.append(song)

    def __str__(self):
        header = f'Album {self.number} ({len(self.songs)} songs)'
        str_list = [header]
        for song in self.songs:
            str_list.append(str(song))
        return '\n'.join(str_list)


album = Album(1)
album.add_song('White_Wedding', 'Billy_Idol', '00:04:12')
album.add_song('Stand_And_Deliver', 'Adam_&_The_Ants', '00:03:33')
album.add_song('You_Spin_Me_Around', 'Dead_Or_Alive', '00:03:14')
print(album)
```

**Output:**

```
Album 1 (3 songs)
01: White_Wedding - Billy_Idol - 00:04:12
02: Stand_And_Deliver - Adam_&_The_Ants - 00:03:33
03: You_Spin_Me_Around - Dead_Or_Alive - 00:03:14
```

Comment: This is perfect for my use case... Thank you very much !